# Gravity form Load By Ajax Cannot Submit - Error 400

Tags: ajax, errors, plugin-gravity-forms

I have an issue with Gravity forms. I successfully loaded Gravity Forms via ajax, but I got an error of 400 when I submit the form.

I tried all solutions but still can't submit the forms.

here is my ajax code

```
var data = {
            action': 'step_3_ajax_content',
            }
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax.url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
        $(".loading").show();
        },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.wizards-content-ajax').html(response);
                 $(".loading").hide();
        }
 });
```

to show forms I use shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]' ); ?>
```

I get error `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#gf_1:1`

in my header `gravity_form_enqueue_scripts (1, true); // Ajaxed form id = 1`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? We have run into the same issue today.

Comment: you need to ask Gravity forms support or in a GF community, 3rd party plugin user/dev support questions questions are offtopic here andnot in this stacks scope

Answer (score 0):

facing the same issue..., i'm try to to load the form with dynamic content,i was  able to load the content and the form but was unable to submit the form.
In network tab is shows as Bad Request
[image]

[image]

I suggest reason is....it is unable to fire the gravity ajax action hook

Comment: i just solve the issue by setting the form action to blank... your form probably have the action set to action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#gf_1" like this...! just remove it using js or jquery  jQuery('your_gf_id').attr('action', '')

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/256125)

Comment: roshan moolya's suggestion of removing the 'action' property on the form works for me.